# How to access(r+w) /sdcard/Android/data folder in Android 11

Tags: android-11

I have created antivirus type app whose main purpose is to clean unwanted caches, logs, empty files and folders from Internal Storage of android. It worked fine until android 11 as Android/data folder is not accessible. This folder contains most junk files.

Please anyone help me to know - how can I access this folder with read and write permissions programmatically without root ?

Comment: "This folder contains most junk files." This is not true. This statement is one of the reasons why other applications can no longer accessible the `application/data` directory.

Comment: No its true.. Most of the app caches are stores in the folder and my app smartly detects those folder by reading names.